# Как мне дополнить авторизацию в моем приложении через Wallet Connect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, авторизация

Я разрабатываю приложение, в нем сделана авторизация через MetaMask. Я хочу дополнить авторизацию через Wallet Connect чтобы можно было авторизовываться с телефона. Подскажите пожалуйста как это делается? В документации нашел только способ реализации с помощью React-Native. Мое же приложение на React. Может есть готовые гайды по подключению Wallet Connect к React. Вот примерный вариант как это должно выглядеть.

[пример](https://app.sushi.com/swap)

Answer (score 0):

Для этого лучше использовать walletconnect ([документация](https://docs.walletconnect.com/2.0/)). Устанавливаете библиотеку, создаете провайдера и можно коннектиться к кошельку, и подписывать транзакции